# Android - WebView font looks different on every device

Tags: android, fonts, webview

I have an application with several screens as HTML loaded in WebView.

The default CSS for texts is `font:normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`, which, as I assumed, is supposed to look the same (in terms of font size) on all devices.

For some reason, on some devices the font looks like size 26+ which causes the font to overflow in constricted elements.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are other parameters play role in determining size of elements in HTML page in Android like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/hdpi.css" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5)">


 <meta name="viewport"   content="user-scalable=no,   width=device-width,  target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

try to integrate those parameters and you will get more stable view ..and then later you may update those values through JS or activity ..

good luck

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem directly of course, but gives the way to control the attached styles and the general way the screen behaves. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this setting for webview .. this sets the initial scale for the WebView

```
setInitialScale (int scaleInPercent)
```